# Cocoa webView - Disable all interaction

Tags: cocoa, webview

I have a webView in my cocoa application (macosx not iphone), it displays some javascript to the user but I don't want the user to be able to select any of the text or right click and select the reload option.

Is there a simple way to disable all interaction with the webView?

I know on the iPhone its easy to disable user interaction but I have never needed to do this on the desktop before and can't find a solution.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Set both editing and UI delegations:

```
[view setUIDelegate:self];
[view setEditingDelegate:self];
```

Then add the methods above to disable text selection and context menu.

```
- (NSArray *)webView:(WebView *)sender contextMenuItemsForElement:(NSDictionary *)element 
    defaultMenuItems:(NSArray *)defaultMenuItems
{
    // disable right-click context menu
    return nil;
}

- (BOOL)webView:(WebView *)webView shouldChangeSelectedDOMRange:(DOMRange *)currentRange 
    toDOMRange:(DOMRange *)proposedRange 
    affinity:(NSSelectionAffinity)selectionAffinity 
    stillSelecting:(BOOL)flag
{
    // disable text selection
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Old, but... for the sake of good form, shouldn't we be returning nil in the first method, instead of NO?

Answer (score 3):

via the UI delegation it might be useful also to disable drag and drop operations, add

```
- (NSUInteger)webView:(WebView *)sender dragSourceActionMaskForPoint:(NSPoint)point
{
    return WebDragSourceActionNone; // Disable any WebView content drag
}

- (NSUInteger)webView:(WebView *)sender dragDestinationActionMaskForDraggingInfo:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)draggingInfo
{
    return WebDragDestinationActionNone; // Disable any WebView content drop
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this stops drag-n-drop of URLs onto the webview.