# (Mac) Changing the window of an NSWindowController to a subclass of NSWindow

Tags: macos, cocoa, subclass, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I'm using a NIB with IB that's unpacked into an NSWindow by my NSWindowController subclass when it's initialized (as normal). [NSWindowController* window] gives me the window of the controller.

Now, I want to make my window controller's window be of a different class that subclasses it. Specifically, I want to override one method in it, sendEvent. This doesn't work, not that I thought it would:

```
self.window = ((WebViewEventKillingWindow*) self.window);
```

WebViewEventKillingWindow is a subclass to disable user interaction (thanks to Bob, found here [Disable a WebKit WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878281/disable-a-webkit-webview)). I'm doubting that this is even possible to do without a different approach, but I'm fairly new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your window in Interface Builder, and ensure that the attributes inspector is open.

The first option in that panel is "Custom Class" - type in the name of your NSWindow sublass in there:

[image]

Comment: Perfect. I knew about this feature but didn't think of using it in this case. The other thing I had to do was connect the window to a new outlet (weak reference) in my controller since the default window outlet is an NSWindow.

Comment: Since you know that it's your subclass, you cold have just cast the default outlet when accessing it too.