# Cocoa: how to disable all the user interactions of a web view in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview

Suppose I have one Webview over another and i am loading a page inside the inner web view.
Now I want to disable all the user interactions of the outer Webview.
How can I achieve this in desktop programming?

Here goes the code segment:

```
IBOutlet WebView *innerWebView;
IBOutlet WebView *outerWebView;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
   // NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"main" ofType:@"html"];
   // NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    [[myWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://icicibank.com"]]];
    [outerWebView setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [outerWebView setEditable:NO];

}
- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView decidePolicyForNewWindowAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation request:(NSURLRequest *)request newFrameName:(NSString *)frameName decisionListener:(id < WebPolicyDecisionListener >)listener{
    [myWebView setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [myWebView setEditable:NO];
    [outerWebView setDrawsBackground:YES];
    [outerWebView setEditable:YES];
    NSLog(@"hello");
    [[outerWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:request];
    [outerWebView webViewShow:outerWebView];
}
```

These are the outlets.

Comment: What do you mean "one web view over another"? And does Webview's `-setEditable:` work?

Answer (score 1):

Check the accepted answer for this question:

[Cocoa webView - Disable all interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251561/cocoa-webview-disable-all-interaction)

The answer talks about a couple of user events. You could select the methods from `WebUIDelegate` protocol and `WebEditingDelegate` protocol which would suit your need.

Answer (score 0):

Put all your html code from BODY between `<div onmousedown="return false"> ... </div>` . This will help you avoid users from dragging images for instance ...

Add this method too:

```
//Disabling the right click menu 
- (NSArray *)webView:(WebView *)sender contextMenuItemsForElement:(NSDictionary *)element defaultMenuItems:(NSArray *)defaultMenuItems {
    return nil;
}
```