# Cocoa Webkit - Disable text selection, but allow textfield selection

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview, webkit

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1251995/904972) I know how to completely disable user selection on a WebView.

I would like to prevent users from selecting text/graphics in the WebView but still be able to select a text field to input text. With the above solution selecting text fields is not allowed.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It appears the changing the delegate to return `[[proposedRange startContainer] isContentEditable]` will allow selection on editable elements, i.e. form fields.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(WebView *)webView shouldChangeSelectedDOMRange:
    (DOMRange *)currentRange
    toDOMRange:(DOMRange *)proposedRange
    affinity:(NSSelectionAffinity)selectionAffinity
    stillSelecting:(BOOL)flag
{
    return [[proposedRange startContainer] isContentEditable];
}
```